# Android Getting null image data

Tags: java, android

I am trying to get the image from the camera. It works fine. I can take a photo and show it on the image view. Actually, I want to send this photo to my server after took. To do that, I try to pull the image in `onActivityResult`. But, when i check the Intent data, it always return null.Even though, the application runs fine and display the image. Why am I getting null for Intent data? Could you please help me?

Here is the code:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        switch (requestCode) {
        case ACTION_TAKE_PHOTO_B: {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                        Log.e("TAG","data: "+data);
                    display_Photo();            


            //Process the image to send but, data is null   
            }
            break;
        }

    } 
    }
```

**Log cat:**

data : Null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the code you are using there are two button onclick handlers that call:
`dispatchTakePictureIntent(int actionCode)`

One button calls it with the enum `ACTION_TAKE_PHOTO_B` while the other call sit with the enum `ACTION_TAKE_PHOTO_S`

If you are passing in `ACTION_TAKE_PHOTO_B`, then the expected result of `data` in the returned intent is `null`.

The reason why is that before `dispatchTakePictureIntent` calls the intent `MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`, it sets an extra intent parameter based on the `actionCode` passed in:

```
takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f));
```

According to the [documentation for ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html#ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE):

> The caller may pass an extra EXTRA_OUTPUT to control where this image
>   will be written. If the EXTRA_OUTPUT is not present, then a small
>   sized image is returned as a Bitmap object in the extra field.

So, because the `EXTRA_OUTPUT` parameter is being set, your image is being written to disk *instead* of being returned as data in the intent.  To get the file location, you can inspect  `mCurrentPhotoPath` which is written to before the intent is launched.

Comment: How is captured image path != previous taken image path?